# How do I add multiple symbols on main timeline

Tags: adobe-edge-animate

I'm having trouble when I add a symbol into the main timeline. It can be seen on the main timeline even when I have a playback command trigger set halfway along. I have one already playing from the start, and I want to add the second symbol and pay this one when the first one finishes.

I have set the playback command to 'play' so the second symbol will begin playing after the first symbol animation is done, but it is displaying before this trigger point. I don't know how to make it hidden until I want it to be seen on the timeline. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide symbols by using an 'Opacity' Keyframe.

To hide a symbol (Symbol_1) between **0:00** and **0:010** I would use this process:

1. Place the playback head at **0:00** and right click on Symbol_1 in the timeline. From the menu that appears, select 'Add Keyframe' then choose 'Opacity'
2. Within the Symbol_1 layer on the timeline you should see a new child row called 'Opacity' and a value of 100. On the timeline itself a diamond will appear under the playhead indicating where this keyframe sits in the animation. Change the opacity value to '0' and the object will disappear from the stage.
3. Place the playback head at **0:010** and insert another Opacity keyframe on the same layer. Another diamond should appear under the playhead.
4. Make sure the second Opacity keyframe is selected, and change the Opacity value to 100. This will change the colour of the the timeline between our two keyframes to green. This green indicates that there is a transition between our two opacity states, if you play the animation you should see your symbol fading from 0 opacity to 100 opacity over 10 seconds.
5. This is great if you want a fade, but you don't! Right click on the green bar between the keyframes and select 'Remove Transition'.
6. If you play your animation now, the symbol will remain hidden until it hits the second Opacity keyframe at **0:010**, where it's opacity gets bumped back up to 100 and it becomes visible.

Hope that helps! If you are still struggling attach the files you're working with and someone may be able to take a closer look.

Comment: Thank you for your clear instructions. This solved my issue straight away. I tried to do this before, but as a novice I got thrown by the transition that was automatically added. Thanks again.